# How to override @synthesized getters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

how to override a property synthesized getter?

Comment: This is neither iPhone or iOS specific. It isn't even specific to any platform or framework.

Comment: "Override" has a specific meaning in OOP and Objective-C. Alas, you probably mean something else: "How to prevent synthesizing a getter and instead implement it manually?" If I'm interpreting you correctly you did accept the wrong answer.

Comment: @user142019: Why does that matter?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Inside of your property definition you can specify getter and setter methods as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, getter = getterMethodName, setter = setterMethodName) NSString *someString;
```

You can specify the getter only, the setter only, or both.

Comment: How to specify getter only / setter only?

Comment: In my Xcode project I do not need to @synthesize someString, in this case how can I set its value? Xcode error says that is an undeclared property.. Thx

Comment: @Mr.Frank: Xcode now does the synthesizing of properties automatically by default. This was added in one of the Xcode versions (4.5?). So, basically, you don't have to `@synthesize` your variables anymore, you just need the `@property`, and in there you just need to specify your getter and/or setter.

Answer (score 76):

Just implement the method manually, for example:

```
- (BOOL)myBoolProperty
{
    // do something else
    ...
    return myBoolProperty;
}
```

The compiler will then not generate a getter method.

Comment: Note that if your `@property` is `atomic` (the default), you cannot correctly mix an `@synthesize`d getter/setter with a manually written getter/setter.

Comment: Afraid of what?  `atomic` isn't *that* useful;  it does nothing to guarantee data integrity in a threaded application.  It just prevents an app from crashing due to an obvious race condition.   If you are relying on `atomic` heavily, you are almost assuredly doing it wrong... :)

Comment: @bbum: could you elaborate on what you mean by "you cannot correctly mix a synthesized getter/setter with a manually written getter/setter" when the property is atomic? I don't understand what one has to do with the other. Thanks.

Comment: Sure; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties may be helpful.  Specifically, since the locking mechanism to implement `atomic` is not exposed, there is no way you can manually implement just the setter or just the getter and ensure atomicity with an `@synthesize`d `atomic` setter/getter.

Comment: if you write a getter method like that, will the property automatically be readonly? if not, where does the data get stored if the property is assigned a value?

Answer (score 43):

Just implement your own getter and the compiler will not generate one. The same goes for setter.

For example:

```
@property float value;
```

is equivalent to:

```
- (float)value;
- (void)setValue:(float)newValue;
```

Answer (score 10):

I just want to add, I was not able to override BOOL property with getter/setter, until I add this :

```
@synthesize myBoolProperty = _myBoolProperty;
```

so the complete code is :

in header file :

```
@property  BOOL myBoolProperty;
```

in implementation file :

```
@synthesize myBoolProperty = _myBoolProperty;


-(void)setMyBoolProperty:(BOOL) myBoolPropertyNewValue
{
    _myBoolProperty = myBoolPropertyNewValue;
}

-(BOOL) myBoolProperty
{
    return _myBoolProperty;
}
```